# Call a stored procedure multiple times and process only one of the three table which gets returned

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to extract data from SQL SERVER 2008 database.Following is the description my task:

1. I have list of records(lets say 100) which I did extract using a SQL query from the database.
2. Some specific columns of each record should be given input to a stored procedure. The stored procedure returns three tables as the output.
3. I will have to catch only one of the table out of three and filter the columns data using another SQL query.
4. If the above filter condition is correct,I will save the column data(of step 1) in an excel.
5. I will have to repeat the process for all the 100 records and save the filtered data in an excel.

I considered it doing with below options but I am stuck and not able to proceed further:

1. Using SSIS
2. Using Nested Cursors

One option of doing that is by creating a user defined function for SP but I cannot do it because the data is in production environment.

Please let me know any process with which I can do it in a simpler manner.

Comment: In step 3, how do you decide which table to catch?

Comment: The third(last) table which gets returned is the one I need

Comment: There should be something missing in the question. How can you know which table to take into consideration that should be part of Case ..Something like if this meets than catch the table and process.

Comment: You can try like this :1) Do first step in Stored proc till catch the table and execute --- DONE in SSIS 2) Do a destination as Excel

Comment: @Maverick I will have to catch the third table and then run another query on one of its column and basing on the output,the data(in 1st step) gets filetered.

Comment: Then it will be more simple then based on the 1st step filtered data you catch the third table and execute the sql query in Execute SQL TASK inside ssis and then give a destination.

Comment: You tried both SSIS and nested cursors an you got stuck. Where did you get stuck? In SSIS, steps 1 & 2 should be straightforward to accomplish. Have you got that far?